# Flask: how do I serve an svg that's dynamically generated

Tags: python, svg, flask

So I have code that generates an SVG xml:

```
def get_map(locations):
    max_value = max(locations.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]
    base = "fill:#%s;fill-rule:nonzero;"

    f = open("../static/img/usaHigh.svg", "r").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

    for l in locations:
       #do stuff.....

    return str(soup)
```

but now I want to serve this svg through flask. To be able to do something like

```
<img src='sometemp.svg'>
```

so my flask function would look like:

```
def serve_content():
    return render_template('sometemplate.html', map=get_map())
```

Is this possible without creating temp files?

EDIT: here's a chunk of the output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!-- (c) ammap.com | SVG map of USA -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:amcharts="http://amcharts.com/ammap" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<defs>
<style type="text/css">
            .land
            {
                fill: #CCCCCC;
                fill-opacity: 1;
                stroke:white;
                stroke-opacity: 1;
                stroke-width:0.5;
            }
        </style>
<!--{id:"US-AK"},{id:"US-AL"},{id:"US-AR"},{id:"US-AZ"},{id:"US-CA"},{id:"US-CO"},{id:"US-CT"},{id:"US-DC"},{id:"US-DE"},{id:"US-FL"},{id:"US-GA"},{id:"US-HI"},{id:"US-IA"},{id:"US-ID"},{id:"US-IL"},{id:"US-IN"},{id:"US-KS"},{id:"US-KY"},{id:"US-LA"},{id:"US-MA"},{id:"US-MD"},{id:"US-ME"},{id:"US-MI"},{id:"US-MN"},{id:"US-MO"},{id:"US-MS"},{id:"US-MT"},{id:"US-NC"},{id:"US-ND"},{id:"US-NE"},{id:"US-NH"},{id:"US-NJ"},{id:"US-NM"},{id:"US-NV"},{id:"US-NY"},{id:"US-OH"},{id:"US-OK"},{id:"US-OR"},{id:"US-PA"},{id:"US-RI"},{id:"US-SC"},{id:"US-SD"},{id:"US-TN"},{id:"US-TX"},{id:"US-UT"},{id:"US-VA"},{id:"US-VT"},{id:"US-WA"},{id:"US-WI"},{id:"US-WV"},{id:"US-WY"}-->
</defs>
<g>
<path id="US-AK" title="Alaska" class="land" d="M456.18,521.82l-0.1,4.96l-0.1,4.94l-0.1,4.92l-0.1,4.9l-0.1,4.88l-0.1,4.86l-0.1,4.84l-0.1,4.82l-0.1,4.8l-0.1,4.78l-0.1,4.77l-0.09,4.75l-0.1,4.73l-0.09,4.71l-0.09,4.7l-0.09,4.68l-0.09,4.66l-0.09,4.65l-0.09,4.64l-0.09,4.62l-0.09,4.61l-0.09,4.59l-0.09,4.58l-0.09,4.56l-0.09,4.55l-0.09,4.54l-0.09,4.53l-0.09,4.51l-0.09,4.5l-0.09,4.49l-0.09,4.48l-0.09,4.47l1.8,0.66l1.79,0.65l0.57,-1.23l1.93,0.97l1.69,0.85l1.09,-1.06l1.18,-1.14l1.58,-0.07l1.77,-0.09l1.18,-0.06l0,0.98l-0.44,1.63l-
```

So I'm trying to pipe that back to the page template without first saving it into a file, and then serving it. Is that possible?

EDIT 2:

this is the routing function

```
@app.route("/map", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def map():
    locations = {"US-NY":60,
             "US-FL":30,
             "US-CA":100}
    #return Response(get_map(locations), mimetype='image/svg+xml')
    return render_template("map.html", svg=get_map(locations))
```

This is my template:

```
<html>
<body>

this is some of the stuff I want, here's a beautiful map

{{ svg }}
</body>

</html>
```

And this is what my page looks like on Chrome
[image]

So it's not actually showing the svg :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SVG code is being [*autoescaped*](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping). An appropriate solution is to call [`Markup()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Markup), like so:

```
return render_template("map.html", svg=Markup(get_map(locations)))
```

Comment: What's the `get_map` function? How can I import it? My program is giving me a `NameError` when I try to run this code. I have a feeling this answer needs to be updated. The doc links are broken too.

Comment: `get_map()` is a function that was provided by the original question. I've updated the links, but feel free to update answers with dead links yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use StringIO for this :

```
from flask import send_file
from StringIO import StringIO

def serve_content(content):
    svg_io = StringIO()
    svg_io.write(content)
    svg_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(svg_io, mimetype='image/svg+xml')
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i  have at the moment, but if I do that, the whole rendered page will be the map itself, that's what I"m trying to avoid I'm trying to include the map as part of the page. So the page will have other content, in addition to the map.

Comment: using StringIO (or fastest alternative cStringIO) allows to work "in memory" without the need for temp files

Comment: you need two "servlets" : one for you page (the one containing <img src='sometemp.svg'>), one for sometemp.svg itself. My code was for the 2nd one

Comment: Since I already have the xml, I shouldn't need to have two servlets to serve the svg though.

Comment: ok, svg element within HTML should start with <svg> and ends with </svg>, Beautiful soup add xml tags, try to remove them

Comment: :'( I've tried that, all the same. I saved the output to a file to verify that the output was correct, if I open the svg file standalone, it works fine.

Comment: What's the <svg>....</svg> content including <svg> tags ? Is there an xml tag in it ?

Comment: I've removed the xml tags but kept the svg tags.

Comment: anybody know why the `seek(0)` is necessary?

Comment: Btw in Python 3 you import `StringIO` from `io`

Answer (score 0):

For those with no need for an actual file, here's how I **make an SVG from scratch** with a custom color and serve it up with Flask.

```
import flask

custom_color_global_variable = 'red'

@app.route('/circle-thin-custom-color.svg', methods=('GET', 'HEAD'))
def circle_thin_custom_color):
    """Thin circle with the color set by a global variable."""
    return flask.Response(
        """
            <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
            ><path 
                fill="{color}" 
                d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111
                    248-248S393 8 256 8zm216 248c0 118.7-96.1 216-216 216-118.7
                    0-216-96.1-216-216 0-118.7 96.1-216 216-216 118.7 0 216 96.1
                    216 216z"
            /></svg>
        \n""".format(
            color=custom_color_global_variable,
        ),
        mimetype='image/svg+xml'
    )
```